# How to check the update count of my NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, count, nsarray

I am adding many `UIView` subviews to my `UIViewController`

A user can swipe (left or right) the subview off the `UIViewController`.

I would like to keep track of the array count so that when it hits 0 and all the subviews are gone I can display something.

I create my subviews in a for loop on the `UIView`` controller and check the count there.

example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++)
{
    self.subView.counter = objects.count;

    // Some More Code Here ...

    [self.items addObject:self.subView];

    [self.view addSubview:self.subView];
}
```

Here I can `NSLog` the counter and get the number of subViews that are in the Array.

In my subView class ...

If I do this in my completion block for the animation,

```
self.counter --;
```

The counter will decrease by 1, but only 1.

So when I swipe away the second card, the count does not change.

What is the best way to keep track of an array count and see it decreasing each time a subView is moved out of the `UIViewController`?

Update:

I did what was suggested and now I'm getting a new issue. Here's a break down of what's going on:

As my subviews are being added I see the counter go up, for example - 6 items are added (0 - 5).

When subviews are removed the counter hits -1 at the end. (Since 5 is the current subview, removing it decrements the counter to 4, etc.)

I check to see if the counter is < 0, set a `UIButton` hidden to NO, but the button does not show.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the count on the `UIViewController` that contains all of the subviews, rather than on the subviews themselves.  Really, each subview shouldn't know about the other subviews... all it should know about is its parent view, the containing `UIView`.

Make the `UIViewController` a delegate to a protocol on the subviews.  When the subviews disappear, have them call a delegate method on the `UIViewController` to decrement the count.  And in that delegate method, put logic to handle `self.count == 0`.

Comment: *its parent view, the containing UIViewController* The parent view is not a UIViewController because a UIViewController is not a view at all. Perhaps you meant UIView?